# Unity 3D - Low Fps inGame and high CPU usage because of animator

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animator

The player animator is reducing my fps from 70 to 10 fps. When I remove it the fps goes back to normal but i need it for the rig builder. i tried a new animator with new empty animator controller but same problem . in the profiler the Animator.Update it using so much CPU.
I have other animators but it doesn't affect the performance like the player animator
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. apparently my script was changing the Right and left hand IK every update . [image]